# wxWidgets Closing window from system menu

Tags: wxwidgets

I am working on wxWidgets, In wxFrame I handled wxEVT_CLOSE event, inside the event handler I called Iconize(). When pressing the close button my window will be minimized it is work correctly. But while clicking quit from my system menu that time also my window is minimizing. But in my scenario I want to close my window from system menu and want to minimize while clicking close button.

This is my handler.

```
    void Frame::OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event)
{
        Iconize(true);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you don't misuse the close button to minimize the window. I think it would be counterintuitive if a window minimizes when I click on the close button.

Answer (score 1):

You can't distinguish between closing the window from the system menu and using the close button at wxWidgets API level. You can, however, do it using platform-specific code. For example, for MSW you can override `MSWWindowProc()` in your `wxFrame`-derived class and handle `WM_SYSCOMMAND` there and explicitly exit the application, instead of just iconizing it, when `SC_CLOSE` is received.

Answer (score 0):

Just process menu command in other handler and call Destroy directly.

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(wxMyFrame,wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(wxMyFrame::idMenuQuit, wxMyFrame::OnMenuClose) // sample for using event table
END_EVENT_TABLE()

void wxMyFrame::OnMenuClose(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Destroy();
}
```